# Why Is my R Shiny app not displaying properly?

Tags: r, shiny

I am clearly missing something here, but I am pretty new to Shiny apps (I have only every made a couple of them before), and I'm still learning the ropes of them.

This app (which will run on its own) works for the input side (a slider and a text input), but the output (which is supposed to be a table) will not display.

Here is the code:

```
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("CHD Risk Calculator"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("BMI",
                        "Your BMI (kg/m^2 OR (703*lbs)/in^2):",
                        min = 10,
                        max = 70,
                        value = 24),
            textInput("Age",
                      "Your Age:")
        ),

        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    inputdata <- reactive({
        data <- data.frame(
            MyBMI = as.integer(input$BMI),
            MyAge = as.integer(input$age))
        data
    })
    
    output$result <- renderTable({
        data = inputdata()
        chdrisk = -6.293 + (0.0292*data$BMI) + (0.07409*data$age)
        resultTable = data.frame(
            Result = "Your risk of Coronary Heart Disease (CHD) is",
            Risk = chdrisk)
        resultTable
        
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things going on here

1. Your `tableOutput()` has been given `outputID=""`; change this to `"result"`
2. Your inputs for the slider and the text are called BMI and Age, but in the reactive, you refer to them as BMI and age
3. The data frame in the reactive has two columns, `MyBMI` and `MyAge`, but later, you refer to them like this: `data$BMI` and `data$age`

Here is a corrected version

```
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("CHD Risk Calculator"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("BMI",
                  "Your BMI (kg/m^2 OR (703*lbs)/in^2):",
                  min = 10,
                  max = 70,
                  value = 24),
      textInput("Age",
                "Your Age:")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("result")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  inputdata <- reactive({
    data <- data.frame(
      MyBMI = as.integer(input$BMI),
      MyAge = as.integer(input$Age))
    data
  })
  
  output$result <- renderTable({
    data = inputdata()
    chdrisk = -6.293 + (0.0292*data$MyBMI) + (0.07409*data$MyAge)
    resultTable = data.frame(
      Result = "Your risk of Coronary Heart Disease (CHD) is",
      Risk = chdrisk)
    resultTable
    
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate that. After I posted this, I noticed the naming issues in your points 2 and 3, but I'm glad they were correct! Your point 1 is something I did not notice at all, and I just didn't follow the tutorial I was using correctly. Now, I have to fix the number that the function produces, but the thing works, so, again, thank you!